# SQL Server: Estimated number of rows incorrect when WHERE data type not casted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm debugging a performance issue in a SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.2500) data warehouse and I came across a "strange" behaviour in cardinality estimation. I have lots of staging tables with a rowversion column. The purpose of the column is to identify new/updated rows that are later loaded into the fact tables. All these tables have a clustered index on the rowversion column. I've manually updated the statistics of this index - using the WITH FULLSCAN option.

In the queries that select the data from these staging tables it seems that I need to explicitly cast the WHERE condition into the rowversion datatype. Otherwise the estimated number of rows is incorrect.

Example:

1.

```
SELECT * FROM stage.LedgerEntryDimension 
WHERE StageTimestamp > 2502412 -- int
```

Estimated vs. Actual Number of Rows: 741556 vs. 19923

2.

```
SELECT * FROM stage.LedgerEntryDimension
WHERE StageTimestamp > 0x0000000000262F0C -- hex format
```

Estimated vs. Actual Number of Rows: 1 vs. 19923

3.

```
SELECT * FROM stage.LedgerEntryDimension
WHERE StageTimestamp > CAST(2502412 AS binary(8))
```

Estimated vs. Actual Number of Rows: 1 vs. 19923

4.

```
SELECT * FROM stage.LedgerEntryDimension
WHERE StageTimestamp > CAST(2502412 AS rowversion)
```

Estimated vs. Actual Number of Rows: 19624,17 vs. 19923 (correct)

How come that SQL Server cardinality estimation is not correct if data type is not explicitly casted? What is the underlying reason for this behaviour?

On the MSDN site for the rowversion data type it states that the rownumber is "semantically equivalent to the binary(8) data type".

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've managed to find the issue for queries 2 and 3. The problem was that the cached query plans were being used and those were obsolete.

The problem with queries 2 and 3 is therefore solved by either executing

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

or by forcing the recompilation with the

```
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

query hint in the query.

However, for 1st query (using non-casted number in WHERE) the execution plan is still returning the wrong estimated number of rows (741556 vs. actual 19923). So, apparently you need to explicitly cast the number to either binary(8) or rowversion. Why is that?